# bash native string manipulation displays jumbled output

Tags: bash, string-substitution

I tried to use the bash string native manipulation for substituting string with my shell variables.

```
var1='123'
var2='2018-01-01'
var3='2018-01-02'
var4='myfunction('var1','var2','var3')'

var5=${var4/var1/$var1}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var2/$var2}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var1/$var3}
echo $var5
```

Expected output:

```
myfunction('123','var2','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','2018-01-02')
```

Actual output with jumbled strings:

```
myfunction('123','var2','var3')
myfunction('123','2018-01-01','var3')
')function('123','2018-01-01','2018-01-02
```

Here the last two characters shift at the beginning and I lose the first two characters of the string.
I can use SED for the same. But I am just trying to figure out why will the bash native string manipulation not work as expected. Is it because I am doing multiple substitutions ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using dos2unix command on the file. The error was due to carriage return (CR) character at the end of var3 content.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to replicate your output with my version (4.2.46) of bash:

```
david@localhost ~ % cat test.sh
var1='123'
var2='2018-01-01'
var3='2018-01-02'
var4='myfunction('var1','var2','var3')'

var5=${var4/var1/$var1}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var2/$var2}
echo $var5

var5=${var5/var1/$var1}
echo $var5
```

and the output:

```
david@localhost ~ % bash test.sh
myfunction(123,var2,var3)
myfunction(123,2018-01-01,var3)
myfunction(123,2018-01-01,var3)
```

For what it's worth, I presume you also mean to replace `var3` with `$var3` in the final line of the script, rather than `var1`?

Additionally, setting `$var4` with the below line would save the replacing of the strings, if that's not mandatory:

`var4="myfunction('$var1','$var2','$var3')"`

The single-quotes within the string value of `var4` don't prevent the variable substitution, as they're within double-quotes already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. However I was able to solve it by using dos2unix command on the file. The error was due to carriage return (CR) character at the end of var3 content.

Comment: You're welcome! Carriage returns can be a tricky one, as editors in Linux tend not to show them by default. You can make vim show them by typing `:e ++ff=unix` when Vim opens, or by using the `-b` option when calling vim.